# R. Selecting observations starting with

Tags: r

How do i filter observations where species starts with "s"?

```
Observations: 150
Variables: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7…
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8…
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7…
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3…
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setos…
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution you can try with, where `grepl()` + `subset()` are used, i.e.,

```
subset(df,grepl("^s",Species,ignore.case = T))
```

Comment: Thanks. But that solution seems to filter variables starting with s (such as septal. with, species etc.) I want to filter observations where species is starting with s (that is setosa)

Comment: @hkolvs see my updates

Answer (score 1):

With Base R:

```
iris[grepl("^s", iris$Species),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Species` is a factor variable we start by converting to character

```
iris[startsWith(as.character(iris$Species), "s"), ]
```

Comment: This will probably be the most efficient

Answer (score 1):

dplyr + stringr solution

```
iris %>% 
  dplyr::filter(stringr::str_starts(Species, "s"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
dplyr::filter(df, grepl("^s", Species))
```